# What's the easiest way to check that a string is not null, not empty and not = "0000"?

Tags: c#

I was using the following:

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ProductID)
```

But now I need to also check that the string is not equal to "0000". What's the most easy way to do this check?

Comment: !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ProductID) && Model.ProductID != "0000" ?

Comment: Wow, this is a pretty basic question perhaps, but I don't think it deserves 5 downvotes. Go vote down the ones that don't even make any *sense* instead...

Comment: And now, in reaction, it gets 4 upvotes? So democratic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ProductID) && Model.ProductID != "0000"
```

or write an extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullEmptyOrZeros(this string value)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value != "0000";
    }
}
```

and then:

```
if (!Model.ProductID.IsNullEmptyOrZeros())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: isn't writing an extension method over kill?

Comment: @Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy, absolutely not, especially if you intend to repeat this logic in many places in your code. Centralizing it in a single location (extension method) is a good way to reuse the functionality.

Comment: agreed!!But she didn't say that she is using it many places :).If she is using it in single place ,then it is an overkill,IMHO...

Comment: I am using it in many places :-)   Thanks Darin. Your answers are always the best.

Comment: Not overkill, absolutely not. (1) more readable (2) more readily understood (3) no duplicate code. (4) no duplicate code. (pun intended) The only thing I'd say is change the method name to something more domain relevant if possible: "InStock", if that's what we're really checking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!string.isNullOrEmpty(Model.ProductID) && Model.ProductID != "0000")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ProductID) && Model.ProductID.Trim() != "0000")
```

I really don't think there's a function for your specific case. It's not very often that people want to check a string for all of those three conditions.

And there's no particular reason to worry about "optimizing" this code anyway. The `&&` operator is short-circuiting, meaning that the string comparison won't even happen unless the string *does* contain some value.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Whoops. I wrote the code too quickly, and still apparently wasn't fast enough...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `IsNullOrEmpty` check, add a test for `string.Trim('0').Length != 0`. This will also catch strings that are any number of zeroes (instead of specifically 4).

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to check if the value is "  "

If in C#4.0 , you should use the

```
!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.ProductID) && Model.ProductID != "0000"
```

Or not ,

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.trim().length > 0 && Model.ProductID != "0000"
```